# Telegram Bot. Как узнать никнеймы пользователей

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Как при написании команды **/get_usernames** в группе выводились никнеймы всех пользователей?

Использую библиотеку python-telegram-bot  13.7.0

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext

TOKEN = 'tokenid'


def get_usernames(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    user_id = update.effective_user.id

    try:
        chat_member = context.bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)
        if chat_member.user.username:
            update.message.reply_text(f'My nickname: {chat_member.user.username}')
        else:
            update.message.reply_text('Not nickname')
    except Exception as e:
        update.message.reply_text('Error group')


def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)

    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("get_usernames", get_usernames))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```